# Non-CrossTargeting GetTargetFrameworks target error with VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I've just updated my VS to ver. 16.8.3 and now suddenly I am getting this error:

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1720,5): error : 
Internal MSBuild error: Non-CrossTargeting GetTargetFrameworks target should not be used in cross targeting (outer) build
```

Not sure at all what to do about this.
We have been working on this project for years and never had such an issue.

Any thoughts?

---

Seems that the problem is with projects that use multiple .net frameworks AND they **referenence ANOTHER project that uses multiple .net frameworks**

I have a MINIMAL sample solution at: [my public drive](https://microdeskco-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/psylvester_microdesk_com/Eh05Awf-ip9HkcoprdS0HrMB--zNVQYfOKaI44mK2AG2cQ?e=biiyJl)

The solution contains two minimal/empty projects that are technically the same except that the one named Microdesk.DbApp **referencing** the one name Microdesk.Infrastructure.

The Infrastructure project compiles fine while the DbApp project throws the above error.

This solution was working fine for us for multiple years and broke with the latest VS release 16.8.3

Comment: Could you please share your `xxx.csproj` with us to check the issue? And mostly the issue might be under `<TargetFrameworks>`.

Comment: You should share it with us and then we can help you find it out.

Comment: Okay, I did reduce our problem to minimum reproducible case, and because stackoverflow doesn't allow uploads I did put it to a public place  https://microdeskco-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/psylvester_microdesk_com/Eh05Awf-ip9HkcoprdS0HrMB--zNVQYfOKaI44mK2AG2cQ?e=biiyJl

Comment: Sorry for that  I cannot access the link said `the link has been removed`. Maybe you could use [github](https://github.com/).

Comment: Here is a new upload for a sample project that reproduces this

https://microdeskco-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/psylvester_microdesk_com/EnGGv_u9t6ZPqaznSfVNVr4Bzq0lU2v4xbmzMGD0Hyw3pg?e=fSWAZm

Comment: This error is also likely to happen if you have a circular dependency between your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, partially my bad.
I did re-compile the **EMPTY** sample project and found that despite the compiler error, the solution does build.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Microdesk.BIMrxCommon.Infrastructure, Configuration: Debug2020 Any CPU ------
1>  Microdesk.BIMrxCommon.Infrastructure -> C:\Work\Microdesk.BIMrx\bin\Debug2020\Microdesk.BIMrxCommon.Infrastructure.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Microdesk.BIMrxCommon.DbApp, Configuration: Debug2020 Any CPU ------
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1720,5): error : Internal MSBuild error: Non-CrossTargeting GetTargetFrameworks target should not be used in cross targeting (outer) build
2>  Microdesk.BIMrxCommon.DbApp -> C:\Work\Microdesk.BIMrx\bin\Debug2020\Microdesk.BIMrxCommon.DbApp.dll
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**BUT** if you try to USE anything from the Infrastructure project in the referencing DbApp project then the Solution will NOT compile

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Microdesk.BIMrxCommon.Infrastructure, Configuration: Debug2020 Any CPU ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Microdesk.BIMrxCommon.DbApp, Configuration: Debug2020 Any CPU ------
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1720,5): error : Internal MSBuild error: Non-CrossTargeting GetTargetFrameworks target should not be used in cross targeting (outer) build
2>C:\Work\Microdesk.BIMrx\BIMrxCommon\Microdesk.BIMrxCommon.DbApp\DerivedClass.cs(1,29,1,4
): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microdesk.BIMrxCommon' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2>C:\Work\Microdesk.BIMrx\BIMrxCommon\Microdesk.BIMrxCommon.DbApp\DerivedClass.cs(5,33,5,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BaseClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I did upload a second sample project named "Microdesk.BIMrx (2).zip" to the previous OneDrive directory

Comment: You could [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) to help other community members search and handle similar issues:)

Comment: There is no workaround. :( This answer was just an addition to the original post and it shows that it is NOT working

Answer (score 0):

When I test your issue in your side, I did not face the same behaviors as you described. So I guess that there is some issues on your current vs environment due to the update. And maybe the update broke some tools of VS.

[image]

So please try the following steps to troubleshoot it:

**Suggestions**

**1)** disable any third party installed extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed**

**2)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder, every `bin` and `obj` folder of your project.

and also delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\ComponentModelCache`

**Then**, restart VS to test again.

**3)** or create a new project and then migrate the content from the old into the new one to test whether the issue is related to your VS or the special project itself.

**4)** If this does not work, do an initialization operation on your VS.

**Close VS**, delete the whole user folder under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx` and then restart VS to test again.

**5)** [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) from the vs_installer

Comment: I will do this asap, but wanted to tell you that this happens on the Azure pipelines too, and started happening a few weeks ago after one of their updates

Comment: See my comments above in the other "Answer"